# Forbid user to access bills/:smthId of another user Node.js authentication passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, request, passport.js

Is there any other approach to forbid user to call *bills/:smthId* and retrieve the data except passing the user id to the service which is handling the route behaviour?

I have two roles USER and ADMIN.

ADMIN role can call anybody's *bills/:smthId*, but USER role can call also any *bills/:smthId* but if the USER try's to call the smthId which not belong to him server should return 403 or 404.

Question is if there is some solution that I can do that check somewhere in auth middleware or maybe in passport config?

```
import passport from 'passport';
import httpStatus from 'http-status';
import ApiError from '../utils/ApiError';
import { roleRights } from '../config/roles';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

const verifyCallback =
  (
    req: Request,
    resolve: (value?: any) => void,
    reject: (reason?: any) => void,
    requiredRights: string[]
  ) =>
  async (err: Error, user: User | false, info: string) => {
    if (err || info || !user) {
      return reject(new ApiError(httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'Please authenticate'));
    }
    req.user = user;
     console.log(req.params)
    if (requiredRights.length) {
      const userRights = roleRights.get(user.role) ?? [];
      if (!userRights) return reject(new ApiError(httpStatus.FORBIDDEN, 'Forbidden'));
      const hasRequiredRights = requiredRights.every((requiredRight: string) =>
        userRights.includes(requiredRight)
      );

      if (!hasRequiredRights && req.params.userId !== user.id) {
        return reject(new ApiError(httpStatus.FORBIDDEN, 'Forbidden'));
      }
    }

    resolve();
  };
```

As you can see from code block I'm checking *req.params.userId !== user.id* but that is the case only if in the requested url I provide user id.

As database I'm using mongoDB with prisma.

And I forgot to mention that I'm pretty new with Node.js!!!

I tried to debug the authentication middleware and passport to find possible solution if I can prevent passing the userId in each request of this kind.